# Installing floating floor on concrete slab

Tags: concrete, laminate-floor, primer, sealer

I need a suggestion on installing hybrid floating floor. I have purchased laminate floor that have got cushion at the back. I need to prepare my concrete slab to install the hybrid laminate floor. Before there was carpet glue on concrete substrate, so I grinded my floor with concrete grinder manchine. I did vacuum my floor but still there is dust coming off the floor due to grinder. So I asked in the store if I can seal with concrete sealer but they told me not to seal if I laying laminate floor. They suggest me to use primer but I doubt it might be sticky. I am not sure what to do with grinded concrete floor before laying laminate flooring.

Comment: What is your actual question? Are you asking how to get the concrete dust off the floor before installing the new flooring? That's what I'm getting out of this. Are you asking if you can/should use some sort of sealer on the floor? One answer addresses adding a vapor barrier, but I don't see anything in the question about that. After reading about [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), _lease_ [edit] your question to, you know, actually _ask_ a question.

Comment: Laminate doesn't really care if the floor is a little dusty.  If there are still bits of loose glue or chunks of anything, you should vacuum those up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lay laminate over the concrete with only the prescribed pad.

Some manufacturers recommend a 5mm combination pad and vapor barrier. Others recommend nothing. Check as to what is prefered for your flooring.

In my location 90% of the homes have concrete slab floors. A vapor barrier is not needed for a floating floor, but can be used as an additional pad if allowed.

There probably was no need to grind your floor. Simple scraping of the glue should have been enough. ( there is a misconception that a subfloor has to be glass top smooth and flat to lay LVP or laminate. It doesn't)

If you wish to cut down the dust from the ground concrete, you can spray or roll on a [sealer/ waterproofer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Olympic-WaterGuard-1-gal-Clear-Multi-Surface-Exterior-Wood-Sealer-55548XIA-01/315988854?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-RM-RMP-GGL-D24-024_011_EXT_STAIN_WS-SB-OLYMPIC-NA-PMAX-NA-NA-MK682732200-NA-NBR-12507-CON-NA-FY23_673&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-RM-RMP-GGL-D24-024_011_EXT_STAIN_WS-SB-OLYMPIC-NA-PMAX-NA-NA-MK682732200-NA-NBR-12507-CON-NA-FY23_673-71700000113569962--&gclid=Cj0KCQjwhL6pBhDjARIsAGx8D5-1DecWRp5c6Um4hwle5P0V7k-I3qM9X2cLmHh874Xv1S836YhE9TMaAourEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). Allow to dry and start your floor project.